# How can I inherit from ArrayList<MyClass>?

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

I want to inherit from some kind of array/vector/list class so that I can add just one extra specialized method to it.... something like this:

```
public class SpacesArray : ArrayList<Space>
{
    public Space this[Color c, int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[c == Color.White ? i : this.Count - i - 1];
        }
        set
        {
            this[c == Color.White ? i : this.Count - i - 1] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler won't let me. Says

> The non-generic type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ArrayList` is not generic. Use `List<Space>` from System.Collections.Generic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ArrayList<T>`. `List<T>` works rather well instead.

```
public class SpacesArray : List<Space>
{
    public Space this[Color c, int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[c == Color.White ? i : this.Count - i - 1];
        }
        set
        {
            this[c == Color.White ? i : this.Count - i - 1] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems `List<T>` doesn't work *quite* like an array. You have to add elements to it before you can set them... `this.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(Space.Empty, capacity))`. Oh well, works good enough :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper around `ArrayList<T>`, which implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`. Something like:

```
public class FooImmutableArray<T> : IReadOnlyList<T> {
    private readonly T[] Structure;

    public static FooImmutableArray<T> Create(params T[] elements) {
        return new FooImmutableArray<T>(elements);
    }

    public static FooImmutableArray<T> Create(IEnumerable<T> elements) {
        return new FooImmutableArray<T>(elements);
    }

    public FooImmutableArray() {
        this.Structure = new T[0];
    }

    private FooImmutableArray(params T[] elements) {
        this.Structure = elements.ToArray();
    }

    private FooImmutableArray(IEnumerable<T> elements) {
        this.Structure = elements.ToArray();
    }

    public T this[int index] {
        get { return this.Structure[index]; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return this.Structure.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count { get { return this.Structure.Length; } }

    public int Length { get { return this.Structure.Length; } }
}
```